# How to extract subtitles from MKV files in pure Java?

Tags: java, subtitle, mkv

does anybody know how to extract subtiles from MKV files using pure Java? (I know how to do it using tools such as mkvtoolnix. I know I could call them from Java but that's not what I want)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the file format specification:

http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html#track

Answer (score 1):

I‘m not quite sure what exactly you expect as an answer. You can of course write your own Matroska parser (specification is available at [matroska.org](http://matroska.org/)) and then simple extract the subtitle stream.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use jebml https://github.com/Matroska-Org/jebml