# Read subtitles from mkv/media

Tags: c#, srt

I've got a problem, I have a `.srt` subtitle file, as external and internal as a subtitle stream, it's easy to load/read the external file but how to read the internal file with `.mkv/media`?

Extracting the `.srt` file to a temporary folder is only a temporary solution. (Not implemented yet..)

I want to read the file directly from the subtitle stream, any Ideas how to do that?

I've written my own `.srt` subtitle filter internally in my media player. Pure C# managed code

To add a little more clarification when you add `SoftSubtitles` to a media file, then it adds the file to the media as a `TextStream` and that's what I want to read.

I'm using `MediaInfo.dll` to read the language of the subtitle streams `TextStreams` but I can't read the actual subtitles..

To simplify the question even more, what I want is to read the subtitles just like I do with an external `.srt` file, but reading it from a `TextStream` is not as easy, because I can see it has a `TextStream` but can't find it, so can't read the `Subtitles`.

If Possible do you know any programs that can `extract Subtitles` in to `MemoryStream` then return the `MemoryStream` to my program?? Without removing the `TextStream`.

Does anyone know how the `DirectSubVob` or `FFDshow` load the `TextStream` from the currently playing media??

Du you know of `Library` that can extract Subtitles??

Comment: This is a bit too broad. Where do you want to start, write an MKV parser? There's various tools and libraries that can help you work with MKV files. Try searching.

Comment: I can already read all info from the mkv/media but I can't get the subtitles. Reading and using is two different things.

Comment: That is not in your question. Show how you currently "read all info" and how you want to "use" the subtitles.

Comment: As I asked and said I've already got an srt subtitle filter, but I can't read the subtitle data from the subtitle stream..

Comment: And to answer your question, I'm currently using mediainfo to read the data but I'm only able to read the headers and not the actual data..

Comment: What is mediainfo? A tool? A library? (I can guess, but it can be both). You really need to provide more context. This question as-is is too broad and unclear. Read the answers to [this comparable question, but for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374934/how-to-extract-subtitles-from-mkv-files-in-pure-java). Without any context, it's hard to get more helpful than what is stated there.

Comment: `MediaInfo.dll` is library to read headers on media file, I can't find a way to read the actual data.. I only wish to read the subtitle stream as I would with an external `srt` file, read the subtitles and show them on the screen.

Comment: How are you extracting the .srt to a temporary folder? It is very much possible to modify this process to have to read it in memory without creating a file.

Comment: I'm using another program for that, and it's only able to extract the subtitles not read them, at the sametime.. The program is called (DVDFab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my `subtitle problem`, with a new custom `subfilter`, made from reading the source code of [SubtitleEdit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/).